# App Engine - Objectify - Storing a byte[]

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'm using the Objectify library for interfacing with the app engine datastore.

In my User class, I store the hashed password as a `byte[]`.  When I put it in the datastore, it is correctly stored as a `blob`.

When I try to load the `User` object back out I get this error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load non-collection value '<Blob: 40 bytes>' into private byte[]`

How do I fix this?

Do I have to change my User class to have the hashed password be of type `ShortBlob`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you retrieve as `Blob` (or `ShortBlob`) and then take the `byte[]` out of that with `getBytes()`?

Comment: I think OP is having problem on somthing like ofy.get(User.class, user.id).

Comment: looks like OP liked the suggestion! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try with:

1. Using ShortBlog in your Pojo User class
2. Converting Byte[] to String using String instead of Byte to store your password
3. Posting a request to [Objectify google group](http://groups.google.com/group/objectify-appengine)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just use a md5 'd string? 
Another possibility is when u try to load the byte, the User hasn't been registered properly by Objectify. there's a link in the 'objectify's' best practices

http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Relationships

that suggests static registration of your PoJo classes.